# Need help making a GPS Tracking application on Android

Tags: android, gps, tracking

I've searched a lot before asking, but I can't make it out.
I'm making a GPS Tracking application on Android for runners & cyclists, like KeepRunning for example.

I tried to use open-gpstracker : http://code.google.com/p/open-gpstracker/source/checkout which is doing exactly what I want with the GPS. But I can't make it to run, I always get errors because I cannot import httpmime, etc... Do you have an idea about this ?

I also tried to do it by myself, but the OnLocationChanged was never called. (Maybe because of the emulator ? I used the DDMS menu to change location, the dot moves but the function isn't loaded) Any idea ?
I was trying to make a "mix" of these two answers : [Create an Android GPS tracking application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096192/help-creating-an-android-gps-tracking-application) and [Drawing a line/path on Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176397/drawing-a-line-path-on-google-maps) but couldn't manage to do it for now.

I also checked myTracks which seems to be the best, but it's way too complicated for me right now...

I just started coding on Android, I'm not very comfortable yet with all this stuff, so thanks in advance for taking the time to read and answer :)

Sylvain

Comment: First off, welcome to Android Development. And second, put some code into your question. And the logcat results too. This way people on SO will know what and where the problem is and will be able to guide you in the right direction. ;-)

Comment: Thanks! For now my first question is how to import these httpmime and other files for open-gpstracker, there's no code involved here, when I use git to get the project it's not working then.

The code that I used for the second question can be found on the 2 pages I gave. I just tried to make a Toast on the OnLocationChanged but not working even if I move with DDMS...

Answer (score 0):

you need to download following .jar file and import it in your project for httpmime
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhttpmime412jar.htm.
Hope this will help.