# How to track currier/package by using android GPS?

Tags: android, gps, tracking

I am currently working on a GPS tracking App for track packages and parcels right from android smart-phone.
After user finishing put their tracking nO., I would like to be able to analyses this data and find their item information.It also can be track location on GPS to view current location in map-view.

-What would be a good way to smooth the track?
I know that I'll need to implement the tracking in a service, and probably show a notification to user for to easier to know thier item have arrived.
-I have read : [Create an Android GPS tracking application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096192/help-creating-an-android-gps-tracking-application?rq=1)
and 
https://code.google.com/p/open-gpstracker/
-and also, what is the best way to do connect GPS tracking information with the user data that  already have in the website?
like my refr.ex :https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=br.com.tribotech.trackpack&hl=en

Comment: You'll probably want to implement the initial notification service with Google Cloud Messaging to save on battery life. http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html and use http://fluidui.com to sketch the initial mockup.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, you need to know the API of the package carrier you intend to track packages for. Package carriers *always* provide an API for programmers to get information about parcels.

Examples

- UPS: https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit
- NZ Post: http://www.nzpost.co.nz/products-services/iphone-apps-apis/tracking-api
- etc..

Then write your app to use these API's. Some carriers may provide a GPS based tracking system, which is what you want for your tracking thing.